# How to install chaincode on a different channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm wondering how you can install a business network on a specific channel.

In my network I have two channels:

1) defaultchannel - chaincode installed and running on all peers connected to channel.

2) blockaviation - all peers added and certificates synced but no chaincode installed.

If I run the following command to install the chaincode:

```
composer network install -c admin@blockchain-network -a ./contracts/blockaviation/dist/block-aviation-network.bna
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error: The business network is already installed on all the peers

This is true for the defaultchannel but I want to install the business network on a different channel.

Does anyone know how to specify a specific channel when running:

```
composer network install
composer network start
composer network upgrade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel is specified in the connection profile (connection.json) for the card being used.  Remember that Composer cards connect to one Channel only, so you will need to create a new connection.json file, then create a card using that profile and the certificates that you already have.

Steps 2 to 7 of the [Composer Multi-Org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html) should help guide you in creating the new card. Once you have that card you should be able to install and start the Network (assuming the channel is setup ok and you have access to it.)